# Update div position after jquery fadein?

Tags: jquery, fadein

I'm going crazy to try to resolve this problem.

I'm working on a parlallax hompage.
When i click on a link on the menu the page scrolls down until it reaches the target div ( i used posittion().top and try also offset().top)

But in the middle of the page ther's an element that shows up with fadein() animation and the fadein  move the below positions elements so now when i click again on one of the links in the menu the position().top points to the old position of the div.

I don't know where to start looking,  any suggestions?

this is the code that doesn't work after the fadein animation:

```
jQuery('a[href*=#]').each(function() {

  if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') &&
      location.hostname == this.hostname &&
      this.hash.replace(/#/, '')) {
    var jQuerytargetId = jQuery(this.hash),
        jQuerytargetAnchor = jQuery('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
    var jQuerytarget = jQuerytargetId.length ? jQuerytargetId : jQuerytargetAnchor.length ? jQuerytargetAnchor : false;

    if (jQuerytarget) {
      var targetOffset = jQuerytarget.offset().top; //alrady try position().top

      jQuery(this).click(function() {
        jQuery("#nav li a").removeClass("active");
        jQuery(this).addClass('active');
        jQuery('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: targetOffset
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: suggestion: show us your current code, what you've tried so far. we'll help you better with something to work on

Comment: what kosmos say was true.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you expecting. refer the working demo. Hope this will help to you.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var the_ul_length = $("div.maindiv ul li").length;
  for (var i = 0; i < the_ul_length; i++) {
    var the_class = $("div.maindiv ul li#i" + i).attr('class');
    if (the_class == "show") {
      $("div.maindiv ul li#i" + i).show(500);
    } else {
      $("div.maindiv ul li#i" + i).hide(500);
    }
  }
});

$("div.maindiv").mouseenter(function() {
  $("div.maindiv ul li").slideDown();
});

$("div.maindiv ul li a").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var the_parent_id = $(this).parent().attr('id');
  $("div.maindiv ul li#" + the_parent_id).attr('class', 'show');
  $("div.maindiv ul li[id!=" + the_parent_id + "]").attr('class', 'nshow');

  var the_ul_length = $("div.maindiv ul li").length;
  for (var i = 0; i < the_ul_length; i++) {
    var the_class = $("div.maindiv ul li#i" + i).attr('class');
    //alert(the_class);
    if (the_class == "show") {
      $("div.maindiv ul li#i" + i).show();
    } else {
      $("div.maindiv ul li#i" + i).hide();
    }
  }
});
```

```css
div.maindiv {
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
}
div.maindiv ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: black;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  padding: 2px;
}
div.maindiv ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: orange;
  font-family: monospace;
}
div.maindiv ul li {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="maindiv">
    <ul>
      <li id="i0" class="show"><a href="">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li id="i1" class="nshow"><a href="">AboutUs</a>
      </li>
      <li id="i2" class="nshow"><a href="">Contact</a>
      </li>
      <li id="i3" class="nshow"><a href="">Hello</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```